# what does it mean to consume a pointer?

Tags: c, terminology

I am new to C and Cyclone. I am working my way thru Michael Hicks' paper [Experience With Safe Manual Memory-Management in Cyclone](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mwh/papers/ismm.pdf).

They say: "We use an intraprocedural, ﬂow-sensitive, pathinsensitive analysis to track when a unique pointer
becomes consumed, in which case the analysis rejects a subsequent attempt to use the pointer. We
chose an intraprocedural analysis to ensure modular checking and a path-insensitive analysis to ensure
scalability. To keep the analysis simple, a copy of
a unique pointer (e.g., in an assignment or function
call) is treated as consuming the pointer."

What do they mean by "consuming" the pointer?  Is this a standard term?

Comment: The last sentence of the citation says "a copy of a unique pointer (e.g., in an assignment or function call) is treated as consuming the pointer."  Is that not what you are asking?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis so this is a term that they have defined in their paper. it is not a standard term?

Comment: @akh2103 It is not a standard term in C, it is a standard term in the theory of linear types and similar systems which forbid aliasing (two names referring to the same object), but given that a new system is being introduced which is not the same as existing ones, a definition is provided in the paper for what it means in this specific case. I would also point out that if you're new to C, jumping in to a fairly obscure research based derivative that hasn't been touched in 6 years may not be the best place to start.

Comment: @BrianCampbell I hear you! But I'm diving in kamikaze-style for a PL class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e.g., in an assignment or function call
```

A pointer is consumed when it is assigned or passed as a parameter to a function.

Answer (score 4):

They are implementing a variant of C in which certain pointers are unique; that is, you can't have two copies of the same pointer at the same time. So whenever you copy a pointer (assigning it to another variable, passing it in to a function), the new copy is considered to be valid, and the old one is considered invalid. They call this "consuming" the pointer.

In the section that you quote, in the original paper, Hicks italicizes this word "consume", indicating that that usage is the one in which he is defining the meaning. The definition of "consuming" the pointer is tracking when the pointer has been copied, and rejecting further usage of it.

This usage is based on previous usage; for example, if you check the references listed to previous work on linear types, alias types, and capability types, you will find them using the word "consume" in a similar sense. From [Typed Memory Management in a Calculus of Capabilities](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/talc/papers/capabilities.pdf): "In a linear type system, aliasing would be trivially controlled; any use of a region name would consume that name, ensuring that it could not be used elsewhere." So the term is based on existing usage, but the exact definition still needs to be spelled out in this paper, as Hicks is applying this to pointers in a variant of C rather than names in a typed lambda calculus.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is the word "subsequent", so to consume a pointer could mean any attempt to use a pointer